# get value from Oauth acces token response and use it in other php file

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

I've configured an API connection to retrieve product data which is working fine but I'm struggling with the acces token which expires every 1800sec:

So I have a **refresh.php** file for requesting a new access token using the refresh token + client secret and ID

```
<?php
    
    $url = 'https://cloud.lightspeedapp.com/oauth/access_token.php';
    
    $postfields = array(
      'refresh_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
    );
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($postfields));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    if ($err) {
        echo 'cURL Error #:' . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
    ?>
```

This works an gives me a new access token when the previous one is expired, here's the output:

{
"access_token":"xxxxxxxxx",
"expires_in":584,
"token_type":"bearer",
"scope":"employee:all",
"refresh_token":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
1

I have another php file **test.php** for getting data from the api which is also working but I've put the access token manually in the file

```
<?php
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer MANUALLYINPUTTEDHEREXXXXXXXXX";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.lightspeedapp.com/API/Account/XXXXX/Item?load_relations=all');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

My question is: How can I echo the "acces_token" value from the response from refresh.php in test.php?

Comment: Only way is to store the token somehow. Easiest approach would be to have your own database and store the token in the table. Or, you can simply write the token to some file and make the test.php read such file and use that token.

Comment: @PavelJanicek Approach is absolutely right. In addition to it, you need to add a 1800sec time check to generate an access token on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You either use session variables to fetch access token from one page to another. Alternatively, You can modify test.php with the following code and eliminate refresh.php file. Here, I have created a function named generate_token which will return access_token value. You can use this value in the below code.

```
<?php
    
    function generate_token(){
    
    $url = 'https://cloud.lightspeedapp.com/oauth/access_token.php';
    
    $postfields = array(
      'refresh_token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'
    );
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, sizeof($postfields));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    /*if ($err) {
        echo 'cURL Error #:' . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }*/

    return $response['access_token'];
    }
    

    $access_token = generate_token();
    $authorization = "Authorization: Bearer $access_token";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.lightspeedapp.com/API/Account/XXXXX/Item?load_relations=all');
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $content;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to store your access token and get this any page by query or you can put your access token information on creating a session and call it on any page.